# How to implement SHA-256 encryption in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, sha256

I need to encrypt my password in SHA256 before making API request . I am not able to find any implementation of SHA-256 in Angular2

Comment: SHA-256 is not an encryption but a message digest (hash).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I used [sha.js](https://github.com/crypto-browserify/sha.js) for this purpose, it is so simple and does the trick!

First `npm install --save sha.js`

Import in your component, service, etc... :

```
import * as shajs from 'sha.js';
```

And then use it as the docs suggests:

```
shajs('sha256').update({stringToBeHashed}).digest('hex')
```

Comment: I use this approach and works well, but you have to omit the {} in the method "update". 
Example:
 shajs('sha256').update(stringToBeHashed).digest('hex');

Comment: When trying this answer in an angular6 project I get runtime error 'Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined' Looking at the stack, I think webpack has trouble importing it.

Comment: @apricity I have a [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/shajs-angular-example?file=src/app/app.component.ts) in StackBlitz (what uses webpack) adding _@types/node_ module and using _require_ to import _sha.js_ module. Hope it helps!

Comment: If you have importing issues I suggest to read [this article](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2017/03/javascript-libraries-in-a-typescript-application-revisited/) about importing JavaScript libraries into TypeScript projects

Comment: I was using it with Angular and for line "import * as shajs from 'sha.js';" I am getting error.
To resolve it add line "const shajs = require('sha.js')" rest is same

Answer (score 6):

Before I answer your question, you should understand that [SHA256 should not be used for passwords](https://www.troyhunt.com/our-password-hashing-has-no-clothes/).  You should also be aware that client-side password hashing is not normally done, but there is a push for it from a number of researchers.  The catch is that it is easy to do wrong.  Guidance [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/387.pdf) and [here](http://ithare.com/client-plus-server-password-hashing-as-a-potential-way-to-improve-security-against-brute-force-attacks-without-overloading-server/).

Now to answer your question, rather than using Angular2, why not just pull in the [Stanford JavaScript Crypto Library](http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/doc/symbols/sjcl.hash.sha256.html) or [Crypto-Js](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js)?  APIs on SHA256 are documented on these links.

Comment: You've provided excelent links

Answer (score 1):

SHA-256 & md5 both are provide hashing not encryption. SHA-256 not provide any angular2 support still now. If you want to hashstring/hashAsciiStr it's pretty simple in ts-md5....

[ts-md5 npm link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-md5)

**Step to use ts-md5 :**

1. npm install

   `npm install ts-md5`
2. Import the class in your component where you want to use

   `import {Md5} from 'ts-md5/dist/md5';`
3. Hash some things

   `Md5.hashStr('blah blah blah') => hex:string
    Md5.hashStr('blah blah blah', true) => raw:Int32Array(4)
    Md5.hashAsciiStr('blah blah blah') => hex:string
    Md5.hashAsciiStr('blah blah blah', true) => raw:Int32Array(4)`

**hopefully it helps you**

Comment: It is 2017, MD5 should really no longer be used, because it was broken some time ago (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Security).

Comment: Actually both MD5 and SHA256 are inappropriate for password hashing.  This is [#4 in my Top 10 Developer Crypto Mistakes](https://littlemaninmyhead.wordpress.com/2017/04/22/top-10-developer-crypto-mistakes/).

Comment: I agree MD5 should not be used for storing passwords. Its hashing algorithm and was compromised . I recommend  using PBKDF2 [link] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) for storing passwords

Comment: It really depends on what are you using it for. Would I use it for passwords? No, absolutely not. Would I use it for simple hashing for, say, logging API when if you dig really deep, you will figure out what is happening and how to send you own request? Yes. There is a real chance you will get to that scenario because spending countless hours on security solution for development logs is something that is unlikely to happen in any workplace :)

Answer (score 1):

Angular 14:

I had to use [js-sha256](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-sha256) for the purpose with the latest version.

Simply import in the component

```
import { sha256 } from 'js-sha256';
```

and use like

```
console.log(sha256.update("secretPass").hex());
```

Answer (score 0):

you shoud import shajs directly fom sha.js

```
import shajs from 'sha.js';
```

and then reuse it :

```
export class AppComponent  {
  hash = shajs('sha256').update('Abc123$').digest('hex');
}
```

Comment: Is this any different to the currently accepted answer?

Comment: @DaneBrouwer the import itslef ->this wouldn't work : import * as shajs from 'sha.js';

Comment: Seems like that should be added to the original answer as a comment rather than a new answer, but that's obviously up to you. :-)

Comment: i m not who gived the first answer